# typeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str,

Tags: python, django

I trie many solutions from the internet nothing worked.. thanks in advance

Error

```
typeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str
```

view.py

```
def notes(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    month = now.month
    year = now.year

    cal = HTMLCalendar()

    events = Note.objects.filter(date_month=month, date_year=year)

    notes = Note.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'notes/home.html',{
        'cal': cal,
        'events': events,
    }
```

Comment: Share the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `datetime()` function return a datetime format and you assign `month` and `year` to a variable to use them in filtering.

so the solution is to convert `month` and `year` to string format.

```
month = str(now.month)
year = str(now.year)
```